# To Replace Name with Another Name in a file

Tags: hadoop

I am very new to hadoop and i have requirement of scrubbing the file in which account no,name and address details  and i need to change these name and address details with some other name and address which are existed in another file.
And am good with either Mapreduce or Hive.
Need help on this.
Thank you.

Comment: First try it by yourself as described below.

Comment: @Sandeep, do you have any common field between these two files which will help in joining?.

Comment: Hi Actually i dont have any common fields but my files structure likes dis in first file acct no ,cust no ,name deatils are dere and in 2 nd file hashno and name details.in my regular cobol now i am scrubbing in cobol by creting hash no from first file using the customer id.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple Mapper only job (with reducer set to zero), update the information and store them on some other location. Verify the output of the your job, if it is as you expected, then remove the old files. **Remember**, HDFS does not support in-placing editing and over-write of files.

[Hadoop - MapReduce Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Hive to accomplish this task.

1. Write hive UDF based on your logic of scrubbing
2. Use above UDF for each column in hive table you want to scrub and store data in new Hive table.

3.You can remove old hive table.